# Find Sum of product of 2 columns in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Find sum of product of 2 columns in LINQ

I have a list of `educationprogram` objects with 2 properties `NOOfPerson` & `Hours`.

I want a sum of product of 2 properties

```
SUM[NOOfPersons*Hours]
```

How can I write a LINQ query for this?

```
List<educationprogram> edu = (from e in dbContext.educationprograms
                              where e.YearId == 2015
                              select e).ToList();
```

This returns the list of object I have to use. But how can I return `SUM[Col1*Col2]`?

Comment: ... this would be a nice linq exam / job interview question :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the two columns are under the `educationprograms` table then:

```
var sum = dbContext.educationprograms.Sum(ep => ep.NoOfPeople * ep.Hours);
```

you can also add a Where clause:

```
var sum2 = dbContext.educationprograms.Where(e => e.Year == 2015).Sum(ep => ep.NoOfPeople * ep.Hours);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var edu=  from e in dbContext.educationprograms
          where e.YearId == 2015
          select new
           {
             sum = e.NoofPersons*e.Hours
           }).ToList();
```

now edu is the list of products of noofperson column and hours column.